# Modx выборка с условием

Tags: php, modx

Сейчас работаю с CMF ModX и возникла задача вывести данные в два списка. Есть такой код:

```
<ul class="faq-list">
    [[!getImageList? &tpl=`faqTemplate` &tvname=`faq`]]
</ul>
```

Но мне нужно вывести эти данные в два списка. То есть одну половину в один список, а вторую во второй. Алгоритм ясен, посчитать количество элементов, поделить на два, пока счетчик не дошел до половины выводим в первый список, после во второй. Вот только как это сделать на modx не имею понятия. Знает кто, как справиться с такой задачей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `getImageList` есть два параметра, ограничение по кол-ву и смещение

```
limit   If set to non-zero, will only show X number of items.   0
offset  The index to start grabbing from when limiting the number of items.     0
```

Вы выводите первый список с `&limit=половине кол-ва` а второй с `&offset=половина кол-ва`

P.S Добавил в ответ более подробное решение

```
[[!getImageList?
&tvname=`faq`
&toJsonPlaceholder=`jsonoutfaq`
&tpl=``
&totalVar=`totalfaq`
]]

[[!getImageList?
&value=`[[+jsonoutfaq]]`
&limit=[[+totalfaq:div=`2`]]
&tpl=`faqTemplate`
]]

[[!getImageList?
&value=`[[+jsonoutfaq]]`
&offset=[[+totalimg:gt=`1`:then=`[[+totalimg:div=`2`]]`:else=`1`]]
&tpl=`faqTemplate`
]]
```

В первом вызове `getImageList` получаем кол-во записей и `json` массив записей, во втором и третьем вызове выводим записи из сохраненного массива в двух вариантах: второй вызов - первая половина записей, третий вызов - вторая половина

Comment: Это верно, но как подсчитать количество?

Comment: Исправил ответ, написал более подробно

Comment: большое спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: правда обнаружил одну проблему. Элемент, который находится по центру, повторяется два раза

Comment: Если этих элементов не четное число

Comment: Странно, не смог воспроизвести проблему, 4 элемента - показывает 2 и 2, 5 - 2 и 3, 6 - 3 и 3, 7 - 3 и 4, т.е. все правильно

Comment: тогда не пойму, почему у меня если не парное число, например 5, тогда будет показывать 3 и 3. То есть третий повторяется два раза.

Comment: а если будет всего один элемент, что у вас выведет?

Comment: c 1 элементом, да выводит в обоих запросах, но это и понятно из логики, т.к. при этом `limit=0` - а это значит все записи, и `offset=0` - тоже все записи, модифицировал третий запрос - если количество записей `<=1` то `offset=1`

Comment: спасибо, теперь с одной все хорошо. Вот только прошлая проблема и не решается, но в принципе логично. Если число записей 5, то 5:2 = 3, округляется к большему, и выводит 3 записи, затем начинает с 3, и выводит опять 3 записи.

Comment: Вы не правы, там нет округления в большую сторону, div это деление на цело, а `offset` считается с 0, т.е. 3 div 2  =1  - `limit=1` - покажет 1 запись, `offset=1` - пропустит 1 запись и покажет оставшиеся 2, может были какие-то изменения в версиях пакета, я проверял на версии 2.9.6-pl

Comment: я думал offset указывает откуда начинать. Так что теперь и я не понимаю как такое может быть. У меня версия 2.4.2. Большое вам спасибо за помощь и потраченное время) Открою новый вопрос, чтобы уточнить именно эту проблему.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31501/discussion-between-valentine-murnik-and-tunker).